# How-to perform a simple AWS/EC2 rest API call with Curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, curl, amazon-ec2

Has anyone used cUrl to manage the AWS (EC2) rest API? Here I picked the simplest possible call, listing running instances. Am I missing something or am I clearly showing ignorance of proper cUrl usage? The only real lead I have is this [post](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2014-10/0006.html) from 2014 aside from the scattered AWS docs which don't show an actual complete example. (I do realize there are SDKs). It's a curl expert I need...I guess and someone to help me get past the over-use of the word "canonical" by the AWS tech writer.

[Rest API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Query-Requests.html)
[DescribeImages Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html)
[Create Canonical Request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html)

Bash:

```
amz_access_key_ID="????"
amz_ec2_secret="????"
amz_host=ec2.amazonaws.com
amz_date8=`date -u "+%Y%m%d"`
amz_date_http=`date -uR`
amz_date_rfc8601=`date -u "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ"`
amz_content_type="application/json"
amz_credential="${amz_access_key_ID}/${amz_date8}/us-west-2/ec2/aws4_request"
amz_signed_headers="${amz_host};${amz_date_rfc8601};${amz_content_type}"
amz_signature=`echo -en ${amz_signed_headers} | openssl sha256 -hmac ${amz_ec2_secret} -binary | base64`
params="Action:DescribeInstances;Version:2016-11-15;X-Amz-Algorithm:AWS4-HMAC-SHA256;X-Amz-Credential:${amz_credential};X-Amz-Date:${amz_date_rfc8601};X-Amz-SignedHeaders:${amz_signed_headers};X-Amz-Signature:${amz_signature}"
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:${amz_content_type}" -H "Date:${amz_date_http}" -H "Host:${amz_host}" -F "${params}" http://ec2.amazonaws.com/
```

Result from Amazon:

```
<!doctype html><html...HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Encountered an Internal Error</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><hr class="line" /></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The AWS API requests are unfortunately not straight forward to implement in `curl`. You are at least missing the canonical request that looks like that (from the example from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html)):

```
GET
/
Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
host:iam.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20150830T123600Z

content-type;host;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

I recently started a litte project at https://github.com/sengaya/aws-micro-cli that implements some basic API calls of `s3` and `sts`. While it does not support `ec2` at this point you can look at the code or run something like this to get the final `curl` output as well as the steps to craft the request:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=foo AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=bar aws-micro s3 ls
```

Full debug output:

```
s3://some-bucket --debug --dryrun
DEBUG - get_bucket_from_s3url: some-bucket
DEBUG - get_key_from_s3url: 
DEBUG - create_request_url: https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/
DEBUG - get_host_from_request_url: some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
DEBUG - array_sort: host:some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:123456789123456789123456789
x-amz-date:20201007T155300Z
DEBUG - array_sort: host
x-amz-content-sha256
x-amz-date
DEBUG - create_canonical_and_signed_headers: host:some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:123456789123456789123456789
x-amz-date:20201007T155300Z

host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
DEBUG - get_canonical_uri: /
DEBUG - create_canonical_request: GET
/

host:some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:123456789123456789123456789
x-amz-date:20201007T155300Z

host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
123456789123456789123456789
DEBUG - sha256: 123456789123456789123456789
DEBUG - create_string_to_sign: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20201007T155300Z
20201007//s3/aws4_request
123456789123456789123456789
DEBUG - create_authorization_header: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=foo/20201007//s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=123456789123456789123456789
curl -v --fail https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/ -H Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=foo/20201007//s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=123456789123456789123456789 -H x-amz-content-sha256:123456789123456789123456789 -H x-amz-date:20201007T155300Z
```

Comment: I don't totally follow, and don't see any curl command.

Comment: @cloudsurfin I added the full debug output to the answer, including the curl